# Disable-Click on Legend in HighCharts Column Graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am simply trying to disable the DRILL-DOWN effect on my 'Column Chart'. Can anyone help? Here is the sample code at Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D8Ez3/

*as you can see, the graph's legend is clickable. I need the items in the legend to not be clickable because when you click all items, the chart returns empty. I rather not have any drill-down for the chart. Any ideas?

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'impact',
        type: 'column',
        margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
        spacingTop: 0,
        spacingBottom: 0,
        spacingLeft: 0,
        spacingRight: 0,
        backgroundColor: null,
        events: {
            load: function (event) {
                console.log(this);
            }}},
    exporting: {
       buttons: { 
       exportButton: {
       enabled:false
    },
    printButton: {
        enabled:false
    }}},
credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Reporting Year']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Millions (mm)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
    enabled:false,
        layout: 'vertical',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 50,
        y: 30,
        floating: true,
        shadow: true
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '' + this.x + ': ' + this.y + ' mm';
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            size: '95%',
            borderWidth: 0},
    point: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                        return true; // <== returning false will cancel the
                        default action }}},
            allowPointSelect: false,
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Yr 1',
        data: [23.7] }, 
    {
        name: 'Yr 2',
        data: [13.6] }, 
    {
        name: 'Yr 3',
        data: [49.9] }, 
    {
        name: 'Yr 4',
        data: [83.6] }]
      });
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You were close.  Instead of:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        size: '95%',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    point: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                    return false; // <== returning false will cancel the default action
                }
            }
    },
    allowPointSelect: false,
},
```

You want:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        size: '95%',
        borderWidth: 0,
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function () {
                return false; 
            }
        }
    },
    allowPointSelect: false,
},
```

Comment: What would be the option if we have pie graph. legendItemClick event does not work for pie graph.

Comment: @RahulTailwal hm, not sure, haven't tried it with a pie graph before

Comment: @RahulTailwal, to do this with pie charts, you want [`plotOptions.pie.point.events.legendItemClick`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.point.events) - it just so happens that the anchor fragment for the `legendItemClick` property doesn't seem to work, so I've not linked to it directly. From the [`API docs for plotOptions.pie.events.legendItemClick`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.events.legendItemClick): *"Not applicable to pies, as the legend item is per point. See point.events."*

Comment: Doesn't work for me (with bar or area charts). I can still click the legend and all data disappears, which I don't want.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I was able to obtain this result: http://jsfiddle.net/gkys5Lpo/24/. However, when I place cursor/mouse over the legend, it would change shape. Would it be possible to make it not happen?

Answer (score 16):

And if you work with pies, you must do :

```
    pie: {
       showInLegend: true,
       allowPointSelect: false,
       point:{
           events : {
            legendItemClick: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            }
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the way to make legends of Highcharts graph non-clickable because whenever you click on a particular legend than corresponding slice become disappear from graph so make graph persist as per business requirement we may make legends unclickable.

```
  plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 1,
        },
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, consider adding some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers.

Comment: CODE ONLY ANSWERS SHOULD NOT BE DELETED.

Comment: why the -1 guys and gals?  the code is so simple it seems to speak for itself. definitely don't think its worth downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

If using **ES6** you can make it even shorter with arrow function, as it's pointing to **DOM element**, you can simply return **false**...

```
{
  name: 'Name of this chart',
  type: 'line',
  lineWidth: 1,
  color: '#333333',
  events: {
    legendItemClick: () => false  // disable legend click
  },
  data: [1, 5, 10, 8, 19, 28, 0 , 12]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-legenditemclick/) demonstrating how to achieve this:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                    var visibility = this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
                    if (!confirm('The series is currently ' +
                   **strong text**              visibility + '. Do you want to change that?')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

from [Highcharts JS API documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.point.events.legendItemClick) (v7.1.1)

> "The default action is to toggle the visibility of the point. This can
>   be prevented by calling event.preventDefault()."

So this is what worked for me for Pie charts -

```
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a useful addition to any of the other answers, you might want to disable the legend hover style as well:

```
legend: {
    itemStyle: {
        cursor: 'default',
    },
    itemHoverStyle: {
        color: '#333333',
    }
},
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/oyps4fj6/